# How do we put attributes inside an element in a XML schema?

Tags: xml, xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            targetNamespace="http://www.google.com"
            xmlns="http://www.google.com"
            elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xsd:element name ="students">

    <xsd:simpleContent>
        <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:attribute name="IDNUMBER" type="integer" use="required"/>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:simpleContent>

    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name ="guy">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

I don't quite understand why it doesn't work. I tried putting attributes and stuff, but I get all sort of errors that doesn't quite seem to have anything to do with what's actually wrong. Earlier, I got Error3033: The content is not valid. Expected is (annotation?, (element | group | choice | sequence | any)*). Now, I get something else.

Comment: "*Now, I get something else*" - go on, give us a clue.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `<xsd:simpleContent>` and  `<xsd:complexType>` inside the `<xsd:element>` tag at the same time. That is not possible, either your new element `<students>` has a **simpleContent** or is a **complexType**. See [3.3.2 XML Representation of Element Declaration Schema Components](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#declare-element):

> Content: (annotation?, ((simpleType | complexType)?, alternative*, (unique | key | keyref)*))

Decide which one you want to use (**simpleType** or **ComplexType**) and use (one of) it.

Comment: can we have a complex type inside a complex type?

Comment: @user2089523: Not sure about this question but elements which are defined as a **complexType** can of course have other elements which are defined as **complexType** as well. So I would say that you can have "a complex type inside a complex type"